# Kafka Streams: custom state store implementation in leftJoin

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

for various reasons I want to use custom, Redis-based state stores in Kafka Streams app, but I'm hitting a wall when I'm trying to execute `leftJoin` on 2 streams.

Here's my code:

```kotlin
val thisStoreSupplier = redisStores.joinWindowStoreSupplier("join-this", window)
val otherStoreSupplier = redisStores.joinWindowStoreSupplier("join-other", window)

val joined = stream1
    .leftJoin(
        stream2,
        { foo: Foo, bar: Bar? -> Joined(foo, bar) },
        window,
        StreamJoined
            .with<String?, Foo?, Bar?>(thisStoreSupplier, otherStoreSupplier)
            .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
            .withName("my-join")
     )
```

That should theoretically work fine, but turns out Kafka Streams is creating a 3rd state store under the hood, according to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamImplJoin.java#L158). Then, [the method](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/KStreamImplJoin.java#L293) that constructs the store, doesn't accept any custom supplier and creates either in-memory or RocksDb store. Any idea how to provide a custom Redis-based one instead? The app is processing too many events to use in-memory and RocksDb is also not an option.

Edit

Here's the actual topology (with real domain names changed to foo / bar):

```
Topologies:
   Sub-topology: 0
    Source: bar-source (topics: [bar.topic])
      --> bar-deserialize
    Processor: bar-deserialize (stores: [])
      --> bar-validation-filter
      <-- bar-source
    Processor: bar-validation-filter (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000003
      <-- bar-deserialize
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000003 (stores: [])
      --> bar-convert
      <-- bar-validation-filter
    Processor: bar-convert (stores: [])
      --> bar-filter
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000003
    Processor: bar-filter (stores: [])
      --> bar-selectKey
      <-- bar-convert
    Processor: bar-selectKey (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000007
      <-- bar-filter
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000007 (stores: [])
      --> bar-repartition-filter
      <-- bar-selectKey
    Processor: bar-repartition-filter (stores: [])
      --> bar-repartition-sink
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000007
    Sink: bar-repartition-sink (topic: bar-repartition)
      <-- bar-repartition-filter

  Sub-topology: 1
    Source: foo-repartition-source (topics: [foo-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000022
    Source: bar-repartition-source (topics: [bar-repartition])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000011
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000011 (stores: [])
      --> foo-bar-join-other-windowed
      <-- bar-repartition-source
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000022 (stores: [])
      --> foo-bar-join-this-windowed
      <-- foo-repartition-source
    Processor: foo-bar-join-other-windowed (stores: [KSTREAM-OUTEROTHER-0000000026-store])
      --> foo-bar-join-outer-other-join
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000011
    Processor: foo-bar-join-this-windowed (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000025-store])
      --> foo-bar-join-this-join
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000022
    Processor: foo-bar-join-outer-other-join (stores: [KSTREAM-JOINTHIS-0000000025-store, KSTREAM-OUTERSHARED-0000000025-store])
      --> foo-bar-join-merge
      <-- foo-bar-join-other-windowed
    Processor: foo-bar-join-this-join (stores: [KSTREAM-OUTEROTHER-0000000026-store, KSTREAM-OUTERSHARED-0000000025-store])
      --> foo-bar-join-merge
      <-- foo-bar-join-this-windowed
    Processor: foo-bar-join-merge (stores: [])
      --> foo-bar-transformer
      <-- foo-bar-join-this-join, foo-bar-join-outer-other-join
    Processor: foo-bar-transformer (stores: [foo-bar-store])
      --> combined-non-null-filter
      <-- foo-bar-join-merge
    Processor: combined-non-null-filter (stores: [])
      --> combined-metrics
      <-- foo-bar-transformer
    Processor: combined-metrics (stores: [])
      --> combined-sink
      <-- combined-non-null-filter
    Sink: combined-sink (topic: foobar.combined.temp)
      <-- combined-metrics

  Sub-topology: 2
    Source: foo-source (topics: [foo.topic])
      --> foo-deserialize
    Processor: foo-deserialize (stores: [])
      --> foo-validation-filter
      <-- foo-source
    Processor: foo-validation-filter (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000015
      <-- foo-deserialize
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000015 (stores: [])
      --> foo-convert
      <-- foo-validation-filter
    Processor: foo-convert (stores: [])
      --> foo-selectKey
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000015
    Processor: foo-selectKey (stores: [])
      --> KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018
      <-- foo-convert
    Processor: KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018 (stores: [])
      --> foo-repartition-filter
      <-- foo-selectKey
    Processor: foo-repartition-filter (stores: [])
      --> foo-repartition-sink
      <-- KSTREAM-PEEK-0000000018
    Sink: foo-repartition-sink (topic: foo-repartition)
      <-- foo-repartition-filter
```

Comment: You should probably tag your question with Redis as well for better luck.

Comment: it's not really Redis-related though , I feel it would be abusing the tags.

Comment: Do you know how to print out your topology for your application? If so we can check where it's creating that third state store.

Comment: @TheOkayCoder I added the topology to the question